# How can I use usb tethering between my windows 10 phone and my windows 10 laptop?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, usb, windows-10, internet-sharing

I wish to share my mobile phone connection with my laptop. Both are on windows 10. I understand this is called usb tethering and that it should work easily. However, I can't manage to have internet access on my computer.

I have a nokia lumia 735. Usb connection works for accessing the phone data. Would you folks have any ideas on how to share internet via usb ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only share your phone's mobile connection over WiFi or Bluetooth. Since the PC you wish to share with is a laptop, it should have both of those available. As far as I know, sharing over USB is not available in Windows 10 Mobile.

To enable internet sharing, go to Settings → Network & wireless → Mobile hotspot. See [this article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/instantanswers/1191e823-83e9-4bd2-81a2-2aecd19f2501/use-your-phone-as-a-mobile-hotspot) for step-by-step instructions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, I can't use both options (no wifi, no Bluetooth on my laptop). I'll leave this question opened in case someone can confirm this is impossible (according to my researchs, it was possible with windows-mobile 8)

Answer (score 0):

You only have wireless options for sharing internet of a Windows 10 mobile device. Incase you're seeking for confirmation then I can. I have suffered from similar situation you're suffering from and ended up installing Wi-Fi card in my laptop. Moreover I can confirm you that it is also impossible in Windows Phone versions 8 and 8.1. However I think something like reverse tethering can be done on a Windows phone 7.x device thanks to Zune. But for Windows Phone 8 and higher I can confirm **you can't share cellular connection of a mobile device via USB**. Moreover, Lumia 735 is no longer supported so waiting for a software update that could bring such feature is also worthless. Maybe this helps.